# How to get google app engine java integration in intellij idea, community edition?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

This page https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html suggests that I can easily create new projects with google-app-engine java support. It comes up in my google search about this topic, with the idea community edition. however, my "new project" dialogue does not look like that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/soof8k29cl1fb9r/Screenshot%20from%202014-12-04%2022%3A15%3A18.png?dl=0

So I suspect this is just a feature in the intellij idea ultimate edition. But then I would expect to be able to download the plugin for the google-app-engine integration somewhere, right? Where would that be? I was only able to find a really old plugin (version 1.1.2) while the recent one is 1.1.4, I am told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Community Edition is not meant for web development, hence it is only supported in the Ultimate Edition:

```
The plugin is bundled with IDEA Ultimate Edition since version 9.
```

[Source/Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=4254)